# How to access previous/later elements within an ngFor loop?

Tags: angular

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list">
  <div *ngIf="item == previousItem"></div>
  <div *ngIf="item == firstItem"></div>
</div>
```

How can we make this type of thing work? That is, how can we access other items in the list either (1) in relation to the current index or (2) by absolute index?

EDIT: What if the list was instead an Observable?

```
<div *ngFor="let item of observable">
  <div *ngIf="item == previousItem"></div>
  <div *ngIf="item == firstItem"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 42):

You can take advantage of the `index` property of `*ngFor`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index;">
  <div *ngIf="item == list[i-1]"></div>
  <div *ngIf="item == list[0]"></div>
</div>
```

You can find more info on `*ngFor` local variables in the docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

Comment: `list[0]` can be also replaced by `first` where `first` you can define in template like this: `<div *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index; let first = first">` :)

Comment: @developer033 ah thanks for the reminder :-) I'll put the link for the docs

Answer (score 26):

Based on the accepted answer, I found this useful to know. If you are using *ngFor with an async call you can do the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list | async as items; let i = index;">
  <div *ngIf="items.length > 0 && item === items[i-1]"></div>
  <div *ngIf="item === items[0]"></div>
</div>
```