# Angular 7 Grouping Data Using *ngfor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Right now i have data coming in like this in my angular application**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymmt4d

[image]

**How can i group and order the data by State and County and display like below table**

[image]

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  data = [
    { state: 'MN', county: '1', item: 0.297 },
    { state: 'MN', county: '1', item: 0.04 },
      { state: 'CA', county: '2', item: 0.019 },
    { state: 'MN', county: '1', item: 0.0374 }, 
    { state: 'CA', county: '2', item: 0.037 }
]
}
```

```html
 <table >
        <tr>
          <th>State</th>
          <th>County</th>
          <th>Item</th>
        </tr>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let dataitem of data">
        <tr>
          <td>{{dataitem.state}}</td>
          <td>{{dataitem.county}}</td>
          <td>{{dataitem.item}}</td>
        </tr>
        </ng-container>
    </table>
```

Comment: is it possible for you to change the data format to be like {state:'MN', county:'1',item;[0.297,0.04,0.0374]} ?

Comment: I dont think i can change the data format

Comment: https://www.competa.com/blog/custom-groupby-pipe-angular-4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you has the data ordered you can use let i=index and check if the before data is eauql using a conditional operator

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let dataitem of data;let i=index">
<tr>
  <td>{{i>0 && data[i-1].state==dataitem.state?'':dataitem.state}}</td>
  <td>{{i>0 && data[i-1].county==dataitem.county?'':dataitem.county}}</td>
  <td>{{dataitem.item}}</td>
</tr>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

transform your data into multiple arrays using lodash.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy

```
import { groupBy } from 'lodash-es'
const states = groupBy(data, 'state')
```

in your table you can have multiple tbodies

```html
<tbody *ngFor="let state of states">...</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-array-of-objects) as a guide, you can groom your data ahead of time (or use a pipe) to create nested objects.

Something along the lines of (pulled roughly from the linked example)

```
key = 'state';
data = data.reduce((data, x) => {
    (data[x[key]] = data[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return data;
  }, {});
```

should produce something similar to

```
data = [
    { 'MN': [
        { county: '1', item: 0.297 }
        ....
    ]}
]
```

**Alternatively** you can use fancy *ngIf and index logic if your list is sorted. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44057610/10747134). Something along the lines of:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index;">
  <div *ngIf="i > 0 && item.state !== list[i-1].state">{{item.state}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here is a fully working solution with a [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sort-and-merge-table-cells-multiple-columns) **with merging of similar cells**.

You have to calculate a `row span` for each item and bind it to the `rowspan` attribute of the `td`. You also have to conditionally render the `td` to display it only for the first item for each state.

For this, you can create a preprocessed array, ordered by state and by county, with added `span` properties for states and counties.

To set the `span` properties, you can count the number of children for each state and each county for the state by filtering the original array.

The goal is to get a array like this:

```
[
  {state: "CA", county: "2", item: 0.019, stateSpan: 3, countySpan: 2},
  {state: "CA", county: "2", item: 0.037, stateSpan: 0, countySpan: 0},
  {state: "CA", county: "3", item: 0.14, stateSpan: 0, countySpan: 1},
  {state: "MN", county: "1", item: 0.297, stateSpan: 4, countySpan: 3},
  {state: "MN", county: "1", item: 0.04, stateSpan: 0, countySpan: 0},
  {state: "MN", county: "1", item: 0.0374, stateSpan: 0, countySpan: 0},
  {state: "MN", county: "3", item: 0.14, stateSpan: 0, countySpan: 1}
]
```

Here is the code:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>County</th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of dataExt">
      <td [attr.rowspan]="item.stateSpan" *ngIf="item.stateSpan">{{ item.state }}</td>
      <td [attr.rowspan]="item.countySpan" *ngIf="item.countySpan">{{ item.county }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.item }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
export class AppComponent  {
  data = [
    { state: 'MN', county: '1', item: 0.297 },
    { state: 'MN', county: '1', item: 0.04 },
    { state: 'MN', county: '3', item: 0.14 },
    { state: 'CA', county: '2', item: 0.019 },
    { state: 'MN', county: '1', item: 0.0374 }, 
    { state: 'CA', county: '2', item: 0.037 },
    { state: 'CA', county: '3', item: 0.14 }
  ];

  dataExt: any[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.processData();
  }

  private processData() {
    const statesSeen = {};
    const countiesSeen = {};

    this.dataExt = this.data.sort((a, b) => {
      const stateComp = a.state.localeCompare(b.state);
      return stateComp ? stateComp : a.county.localeCompare(b.county);
    }).map(x => {
      const stateSpan = statesSeen[x.state] ? 0 :
        this.data.filter(y => y.state === x.state).length;

      statesSeen[x.state] = true;

      const countySpan = countiesSeen[x.state] && countiesSeen[x.state][x.county] ? 0 :
        this.data.filter(y => y.state === x.state && y.county === x.county).length;

      countiesSeen[x.state] = countiesSeen[x.state] || {};
      countiesSeen[x.state][x.county] = true;

      return { ...x, stateSpan, countySpan };
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the resulting table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
interface Item {
  state?: string;
  county?: string;
  item: number;
}

private processData(data: any[]): Item[] {
  // Sort alphabetically
  const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => {
    if(a.state < b.state) { return -1; }
    if(a.state > b.state) { return 1; }
    return 0;
  });

  // Return original object if state value is different to
  // previous object (or if first iteration). Otherwise
  // return object with sole `item` property.
  return sorted.map((el, i) => {
    if (i === 0 || sorted[i-1].state !== el.state) {
      return el;
    } else {
      return {
        item: el.item
      };
    }
  });
}
```

That should be `O(log n)` complexity and the result will look like this:

```
[
  { state: 'CA', county: '2', item: 0.019 },
  { item: 0.037 },
  { state: 'MN', county: '1', item: 0.297 },
  ...
]
```